# Probability that a randomly chosen element from set $A = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 1000\}$ is a multiple of $2$ OR $3$.

Tags: probability

> Let $A=\{1,2,3,...,1000\}$. Find the probability that a randomly chosen element of $A$ would be a multiple of $2$ *OR* $3$.

My Attempt:

There are $500$ numbers multiples of $2$($\frac {1000}2$). And$\left[\frac{1000}{3}\right]=333$ multiples of $3$ and $\left[\frac{1000}{6}\right]=166$ multiples of $6$, then the favorable cases are: $500+333-166=667$. Then the probability is: $P=\frac {667}{1000}$. Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: You are correct!!

Comment: Makes sense. But do you understand why from a Union definiton? $P(A \cup B) = P (A) + P (B) - P (A \cap B)$.

Comment: @TonyHellmuth Kind of, can you explain more about this in an answer type of form and maybe give some examples?

Comment: Sure. Let $A $ be the event the numbers are divisible by 2. Let $B $ be the event the numbers are divisible by 3. Then the probability a set of numbers are divisible by $2$ OR $3$ is the probability they are divisible by $2$ plus the probability they are divisible by $3$ minus the probability they are divisible by both $2$ AND $3$. Which happens to be exactly what you have written :)